# Inner function cannot access outer functions variable

Tags: javascript

I have created the following jsfiddle which highlights my problem. 
http://jsfiddle.net/UTG7U/

```
var ExampleObject = function() {
   var myArray = new Array();
   this.example = function() {
       alert(this.myArray);
   };
}

var exampleObj = new ExampleObject();
exampleObj.example();​
```

I am new to JavaScript and trying to create an object, field and a method. 
I can't get my method to access my field variable.

Comment: It's recommended you use the array literal `[]` to create an array instead of `new Array();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you were trying to access a local variable using this operator which is wrong, so here is the working example

```
var ExampleObject = function() {
   var myArray = new Array(1,2,3);
   this.example = function() {
       alert(myArray);
   };
}
var exampleObj = new ExampleObject();
exampleObj.example();​
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/3QN37/

Answer (score 7):

You have confused two types of variables: Local variables and member variables. `var myArray` is a local variable. `this.myArray` is a member variable.

Solution using only local variables:

```
var ExampleObject = function() {
   var myArray = new Array(); // create a local variable
   this.example = function() {
       alert(myArray); // access it as a local variable
   };
}

var exampleObj = new ExampleObject();
exampleObj.example();​
```

Solution using only member variables:

```
var ExampleObject = function() {
   this.myArray = new Array(); // create a member variable
   this.example = function() {
       alert(this.myArray); // access it as a member variable
   };
}

var exampleObj = new ExampleObject();
exampleObj.example();​
```

Comment: You answered this quite a while ago, but I don't think your second answer would work.  In that case, 'this' is referring to the inner function, not the outer.

Comment: Try it. It works. That's because `this` refers to "the thing before the dot" which in this case is `exampleObj`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `this.myArray`. Using `myArray` alone will suffice (and work).

Answer (score 1):

`alert(myArray);` should work fine I think

Answer (score 1):

What `this` is changes with the scope of each function. However, `myArray` will be visible to inner function. Example:

```
var ExampleObject = function() {
   var myArray = new Array();
   this.example = function() {
       alert(myArray);
   };
}
var exampleObj = new ExampleObject();
exampleObj.example();​
```