# Inner function cannot access outer function variable after being changed

Tags: javascript

Yes, this question is similar with [Inner function cannot access outer functions variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239129/inner-function-cannot-access-outer-functions-variable). But it's not the same one. What confused me is "after being changed". Codes below maybe more intuitively.

```
var serial_maker = function() {
    var prefix = '',
        seq = 0;
    return {
        set_prefix: function(p) {
            prefix = String(p);
        },
        set_seq: function(s) {
            seq = s;
        },
        gensym: function() {
            var result = prefix + seq;
            seq += 1;
            return result;
        }
    };
};
var seqer = serial_maker();
seqer.set_prefix('Q');
seqer.set_seq(1000);
seqer.gensym(); // 'Q1000'

// Rewrite set_seq method
seqer.set_seq = function() {
    seq = 2000;
};
seqer.set_seq();

seqer.gensym(); // 'Q1001', which was expected 'Q2000'
```

So this is what i want to figure out —— why the rewritten `set_seq` method didn't change value of the private variable `seq` in outer function?

Hope i could get some essential answers, thanks =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new closure. The returned function seqer.set_seq is a closure which can access the private variable seq. But the newly defined seqer.set_seq is creating a new closure which cannot access the private variable, instead it creates a new global one `window.seq`

Try it:

```
var serial_maker = function() {
    var prefix = '',
        seq = 0;
    return {
        set_prefix: function(p) {
            prefix = String(p);
        },
        set_seq: function(s) {
            seq = s;
        },
        gensym: function() {
            var result = prefix + seq;
            seq += 1;
            return result;
        }
    };
};
var seqer = serial_maker();
seqer.set_prefix('Q');
seqer.set_seq(1000);
seqer.gensym(); // 'Q1000'

// Rewrite set_seq method
seqer.set_seq = function() {
    seq = 2000;
};
seqer.set_seq();

seqer.gensym(); // Q1001 is correct!

console.log(window.seq); // 2000
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually another `seq` variable. When you run `set_seq` for the first time, the `seq` variable is already bounded to it, it does not read it directly from the function declaration.

In other words, when you define your original function, an object with `set_prefix`, `set_seq` and `gensym` is returned, and each of these function already have a reference to the `seq` variable, which is defined in the function's closure. When you assign a new function to the returned object, it does not have the concept of the original `seq` variable.

Answer (score 1):

As @devnull69 has mentioned, you have created a closure and your seq is looking on global. If you want to modify your methods after the fact, maybe have a look at prototypes.

```
// Constructor
var Serial_maker = function() {
    var prefix = '', seq = 0;
};

// Define the methods
Serial_maker.prototype.set_prefix = function(p) {
    prefix = String(p);
};

Serial_maker.prototype.set_seq = function(s) {
    seq = s;
}

Serial_maker.prototype.gensym = function() {
    var result = prefix + seq;
    seq += 1;
    return result;
}

// Create the object with new
var seqer = new Serial_maker();

seqer.set_prefix('Q');

seqer.set_seq(1000);

seqer.gensym();

// You can modify the methods on the
// constructor's prototype anywhere in the code
// and it will apply to all objects that were created
// with it.
Serial_maker.prototype.set_seq = function(s) {
    seq = 2000;
}

seqer.set_seq();

console.log(seqer.gensym()); // Output is 'Q2000'
```

Comment: This makes the `seq` and `prefix` variables global, they are not those defined in `Serial_maker`. It would be better to make them instance variables (`this.seq`, `this.prefix`); but I'm assuming the OP has them *"private"* for a reason. I'm not sure why prototypes are necessary here, considering there is only one instance.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek so have this? this.prefix = '', this.seq = 0;

Comment: Well it's an assumption, the OP might want them to be static. They defined why is a certain thing is not happening in their code, it's not clear if or how they want to change the code so it works as they would expect.

Answer (score -1):

Try using your var seq = 0 as global. i.e. Without var.

```
var prefix = ''; // scope :- local

seq = 0; // scope :- global
```