# How do I access a member of the same javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object, scope

Say I have the following object definition:

```
var car = function (engine) { 
    this.engine = engine;

    this.calculateSpeed = function () {
        return engine.power * 20;
    };
};
```

the `engine` object in the `calculateSpeed()` function refers to the engine object passed in via the constructor and not the car's public engine member(which is the one I want).

If I wanted to change the engine of the car after creating the car object I want the `calcuateSpeed()` function to reference the new engine.

The [Inner function cannot access outer functions variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239129/inner-function-cannot-access-outer-functions-variable) question is similar to mine. But does not quite cover my use case as the OP is using a local variable and has no constructor.

If you could also explain why this won't work, that would also help a lot:

```
var car = function (engineInit) { 
    this.engine = engineInit;

    this.calculateSpeed = function () {
        return engine.power * 20;
    };
};
```

I know for this simple example I could use `this.calculateSpeed = engine.power * 20;` but for my real use case, I need a function.

Comment: what problem are you having using `this.engine.power`?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, `this.engine.power` is scoped to the `calculateSpeed` function and not to the car object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What underlies this JavaScript idiom: var self = this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962033/what-underlies-this-javascript-idiom-var-self-this)

Comment: @StormMuller not sure a I agree. Did you check my answer?

Comment: @user3210641 yea, you're right. Seemed I was experiencing a closure issue. I accepted Josh's as it answered the question I posted. As well as helped me avoid my closure issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use `this.engine.power`.

```js
// Define Car constructor
const Car = function (engineInit) { 
    this.engine = engineInit;

    this.calculateSpeed = function () {
        return this.engine.power * 20;
    };
};

// Create new car instance
const carInstance = new Car({ power: 100 });

// Log the result of calculateSpeed function
console.log(carInstance.calculateSpeed());
```

Comment: @Musa why did you edit the answer? Or more accurately why did you add unrelated code?

Comment: To show that in the calculation the engine being used is not the one passed in the constructor. If the edit is wrong you can always undo it.

Comment: How would the `this` keyword behave if `calculateSpeed` had a local `engine` variable?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the internal `engine` to be separate from the `engine` property visible on the outside of the instantiated `Car`, you might consider simply having another locally scoped variable, separate from the initial `engine` parameter, and reassigning it as necessary:

```js
var Car = function(initialEngine) {
  this.engine = initialEngine;
  let engine = initialEngine;
  this.calculateSpeed = function() {
    return engine.power * 20;
  };
  this.changeEngine = function(newEngine) {
    engine = newEngine;
  }
};

var car = new Car({ power: 20 });
console.log(car.calculateSpeed());
car.changeEngine({ power: 40 });
console.log(car.calculateSpeed());
```

Comment: now add `console.log(car.engine.power);` to the last line. Car's engine hasn't changed.

Comment: I thought you said you wanted them to be different for some reason? `refers to the engine object passed in via the constructor and not the car's public engine member(which is the one I want).` If you actually do want to assign to the property of the instantiated object, just assign to it as normal, `this.engine = newEngine`

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of many other questions on stackoverflow, but here is something to get you started anyway.

By capturing this in another variable:

```
var car = function(engineInit) { 
  this.engine = engineInit;
  var self = this;
  this.calculateSpeed = function () {
    return self.engine.power * 20;
  };
};
```

By using bind:

```
var car = function(engineInit) { 
  this.engine = engineInit;
  this.calculateSpeed = function () {
    return this.engine.power * 20;
  }.bind(this);
};
```

By using a function's prototype:

```
function Car(engine) { 
  this.engine = engine;
}

Car.prototype.calculateSpeed = function() {
  return this.engine.power * 20;
};

var engine = new Engine();
var car = new Car(engine);
var speed = car.calculateSpeed();
```

Comment: Cool thanks Josh, could you please add the duplicates to my question, so that other who come here can see them too? Also I like the `var self = this` solution. Bind is changing scope of the local function which seems like a code smell and the prototype solution means that my object lives in 2 places which is also not ideal. Thanks!

Comment: Prototype is actually your best pick as you can only create the `calculateSpeed` function once. In all the other instances (including the one mentioned in my answer) you create new function every time you create a new Car instance.